# Perform task until the file gets deleted in Ansible

Tags: ansible, runtime-error, kill

I will to fire the kill command until the file "/proc/pid/status" or folder "/proc/pid" gets deleted.

Below is my playbook for the same:

```
- name: Kill running processes

  shell: "kill -9 {{ item }}"
  retries: 5
  delay: 4
  until: "/proc/{{ item }}/status is exists"
  with_items: "{{ running_processes.stdout_lines }}"
```

However, my playbook fails with the below error.

```
TASK [Kill running processes] **************************************************
[1;30mtask path: /app/scripts/test.yml:182[0m
[1;35mdelimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: /proc/{{ item }}/status is exists[0m
[1;35m[0m
[0;31mfatal: [10.9.9.131]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '/proc/{{ item }}/status is exists' failed. The error was: Invalid conditional detected: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1)"}[0m
```

I'm on the latest version of Ansible.

Can you please suggest what is the issue with my playbook code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is "Invalid conditional detected", which is correct.  You've written:

```
  until: "/proc/{{ item }}/status is exists"
```

When you write a boolean expression like this, the syntax is:

```
<value> is <test>
```

Where `<value>` needs to be either a literal value (like a string, or a number) or a variable name.  You have `/proc/<some number>/status`, which is none of those things.  You could make the expression *syntactically* correct by quoting the `/proc` path, like this:

```
  until: "'/proc/{{ item }}/status' is exists"
```

But there's still a problem: the condition is evaluated in an implic jinja2 templating context, which means you never use `{{...}}` markers (this is true for both `until` and `when`).  Inside a templating context, you refer to variables by name only, and use string formatting or string concatenation to put them together with other strings. For example:

```
  until: "'/proc/%s/status' % item is exists"
```

Or:

```
  until: "'/proc/{}/status'.format(item) is exists"
```

Lastly, I think you mean `is not exists`, because you're killing a process and waiting for it to die.

---

While the above gives you a syntactically correct conditional, it's important to note this bit from the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html):

> Like all templating, tests always execute on the Ansible controller, not on the target of a task, as they test local data.

If you are targeting a remote host, remember that the `is exists` task will execute on the host *where you are running ansible*, **not** on the remote host.

Comment: In short the entire logic for what i wish to achieve incorrect. I will rewrite the the logic by adding more commands to shell like: shell: "kill -9 {{ item }}; ls -l /proc/{{ item }}/status" and registering the output and checking the registered variable in until condition. Hope that will work.

Comment: I was able to achieve a clean kill with my new approach. @larsks your answer really helped. Many thanks. Sorry for b being mean but can you help answer another query of mine posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58979061/is-it-possible-to-read-set-fact-of-a-dynamically-constructed-host-in-different-a